# Save frontend logs to file with angular packaged in electron

Tags: angular, file, logging, electron

I need to save every click of button and every event on frontend to a single log file. File should be created every time we start desktop application. I've researched about many libraries that could allow me to implement that but every time I see angular cant save files. Advantage of my app is that we open it with electron. Is that any way to save every event to file with angular packaged in electron?

I wonder about solution (library or something that can let me save logs to file with angular packaged in electron)

Comment: Electron has to be responsible for files manipulation. Angular should just send log messages to Electron. Look for the 'Angular Electron Communication'